# ¿Cómo aplicar la propiedad filter a un elemento sin afectar a sus elementos hijos?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Hola hice una animacion en mi pagina que cuando pongo el mouse encima se oscurece, pero tambien se oscurece el texto que contiene. Quiero que el texto no se oscurezca. Aquí dejo una parte del codigo. PD: He intentado con muchas cosas pero ninguna da efecto, se puede ver en el codigo los intentos. Ignoren la consola de aqui, no carga el 100% del programa.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#U1-1").hover(function(){
                    $("#U1-1").removeClass("NoSeleccionado");
                    $("#U1-1").addClass("Seleccionado");
                    $("#txt1").removeClass("Nt");
                    $("#txt1").addClass("St");
                },
                function(){
                    $("#U1-1").addClass("NoSeleccionado");
                    $("#U1-1").removeClass("Seleccionado");
                    $("#txt1").addClass("Nt");
                    $("#txt1").removeClass("St");

                }); 
            });
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: -1;
}
.title {
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
 display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 3em;
    z-index: 3;
}
.Nt {
 color: #000000;
}
.St {
 color: #ffffff;
 filter:brightness(200%);
}
.cursor {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.bordern {
 border: 0px;
}
.NoSeleccionado {
    filter:brightness(1);
}
.Seleccionado {
 filter:brightness(0.2);
 z-index: -1;
}
#U1-1 {
 position: absolute;
 height: 220px;
 width: 273px;
 background-color: #FD4C00;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" id="U1-1" class="cursor bordern">
  <p class="Roboto title bold Nt" id="txt1">Nuevo pedido</p>
 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

La propiedad `filter` va a aplicar sus estilos al elemento **y a todos sus descendientes.**

Te propongo englobar tanto el enlace como el texto dentro de un contenedor y sacar el texto fuera del enlace. De esta manera, el texto ya no será un hijo del enlace.

Por último, le diremos al contenedor que se posicione con `position: relative` y así de esta manera podremos posicionar el texto con `position: absolute` para que se posicione en función del contenedor. Mediante flexbox y la propiedad `align-items: center;` podremos centrar el texto verticalmente.

**NOTA:** Ten en cuenta que en el JQuery he modificado `$("#U1-1");` por `$("#contenedor")` para que se realice el efecto, ya que de lo contrario al no estar el texto dentro del enlace, este impedirá que se lance el hover.

Tu ejemplo modificado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#contenedor").hover(function(){
        $("#U1-1").removeClass("NoSeleccionado");
        $("#U1-1").addClass("Seleccionado");
        $("#txt1").removeClass("Nt");
        $("#txt1").addClass("St");
    },
    function(){
        $("#U1-1").addClass("NoSeleccionado");
        $("#U1-1").removeClass("Seleccionado");
        $("#txt1").addClass("Nt");
        $("#txt1").removeClass("St");
    }); 
});
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

#contenedor{ /* NUEVO */
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 220px;
 width: 273px;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
  z-index: -1;
}

.cursor {
 cursor: pointer;
}

#U1-1 {
 height: 100%; /* MODIFICADO */
 width: 100%; /* MODIFICADO */
 background-color: #FD4C00;
}

.NoSeleccionado {
  filter:brightness(1);
}

.Seleccionado {
 filter:brightness(0.2);
 z-index: -1;
}

.Nt {
 color: #000000;
}
.St {
 color: #ffffff;
 filter:brightness(200%);
}

.cursor {
 cursor: pointer;
}
.bordern {
 border: 0px;
}

.title {
  position: absolute; /* NUEVO */
  display: inline-block; /* NUEVO */
 text-decoration: none;
 text-align: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenedor">
  <a href="#" id="U1-1" class="cursor bordern"></a>
  <p class="Roboto title bold Nt" id="txt1">Nuevo pedido</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Veo que cuando le pasas el mouse por encima, el hover reacciona y el texto se pone gris. Si lo que quieres es evitar eso, acá te dejo la solución:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: -1;
  color: #000000;
}

.a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: orange;
}

.title {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 3em;
  z-index: 3;
}

.a:hover {
  filter: brightness(0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="a" id="a">
  <a href="https://google.com" class="b">
    <p class="Roboto title bold c">Nuevo pedido</p>
  </a>
</div>
```

Oscuro se va ha ver, porque lógicamente le estás aplicando un filtro, pero el texto se va a mantener del mismo color. Déjame saber si no entiendes algo o necesitas algo más específico.