# Backgroung img con filter y nav

Tags: html, css, web, div, nav

tengo la siguiente duda:
tengo un div con un background img, le agrege un filter brightness, pero, eso tambien afecto a lo que tengo junto a esa imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el codigo del html:

```
<header>
   <div id="logo-page">
        <div id="top-bar">
            <nav>
                <a href="#" class="menu">home</a>
                <a href="#work" class="menu">work</a>
                <a href="#projects" class="menu">projects</a>
                <a href="#gallery" class="menu">gallery</a>
                <a href="#papers" class="menu">papers</a>
                <a href="#" class="menu">contact</a>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div><!-- Logo -->
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#logo-page{
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
background-image: url("../img/logo.jpg");
width: auto;
height: 100vh;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
filter:brightness(0.5);
```

}

la idea es que el  nav o en su efecto, lo que agrege adentro de  no se vea afectado por el filter

Comment: ¿Has intentado añadir la propiedad **z-index** a tu top-bar? O bien, ¿Probaste con **logo-page:before**? [Más información](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20039965)

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, probe con ambos, pero tampoco me funciona :(

Comment: ¿Puedo ver como lo implementaste?

Comment: #top-bar nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    z-index: -1;
    
}
y con valor 1 
, probe asi primero, luego agrege el ::before en logo-page::before, pero con esto la imagen desaparece totalmente

Comment: #top-bar{z-index: 9999; } prueba así...

Comment: tampoco me tomo asi :'(

Comment: Lamentablemente, cuando aplicas un filtro a un div padre, este afectará tambien a los hijos, en internet existen "trucos" para remediarlo, pero rara vez funcionan. Te recomiendo hacer ese filtro directamente a la imagen con algun programa de edición y no pasarle un filtro en css

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo aplicar la propiedad filter a un elemento sin afectar a sus elementos hijos?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/148301/c%c3%b3mo-aplicar-la-propiedad-filter-a-un-elemento-sin-afectar-a-sus-elementos-hijo)

Answer (score 0):

Una solución que se me ocurre es la siguiente.

```css
#logo-page {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  filter: brightness(0.2);
}

#top-bar {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div>
    <div id="top-bar">
        <nav>
        <a href="#" class="menu">home</a>
        <a href="#work" class="menu">work</a>
        <a href="#projects" class="menu">projects</a>
        <a href="#gallery" class="menu">gallery</a>
        <a href="#papers" class="menu">papers</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu">contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    <img id="logo-page" src="http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920/" alt="" />
    <!-- Logo -->
</header>
```

De esta forma consigues que tu background y tu navbar estén separados y el filtro lo puedes aplicar con toda libertad.

También te propongo esta solución que creo que va mas de acuerdo a lo que buscas.

```css
#logo-page {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  filter: brightness(0.2);
}

html{
    /* la imagen a ser mostrada a pantalla completa */
    background:url('http://lorempixel.com/1920/1920/') no-repeat center center;
 
    /* nos aseguramos que el elemento ocupe toda la ventana del navegador */
    min-height:100%;
 
    /* Propiedad a utilizar para la imagen */
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div>
    <div id="top-bar">
        <nav>
        <a href="#" class="menu">home</a>
        <a href="#work" class="menu">work</a>
        <a href="#projects" class="menu">projects</a>
        <a href="#gallery" class="menu">gallery</a>
        <a href="#papers" class="menu">papers</a>
        <a href="#" class="menu">contact</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Logo -->
</header>
```